# Google maps addDomListener to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I need some assistance. I want to change from addDomListener to addEventListener but I don't know how can I change it. Can someone please help me with this problem. Thank you.

In HTML:

```
<div class="map-container">
   <div id="id-map"></div>
</div>
```

In JS:

```
$.getScript( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + google_api_key + "&libraries=places") 
.done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap)

})

function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('id-map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: {lat: lat_a, lng: long_a}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```

Reason of change because this error is showing into the console and the map is not showing into the frontend.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated
```

Can anyone please help me? I need this fix as soon as possible. I appreciate for your help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a to add an event listener to the window like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", initMap);
```

This should work.

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Checkout this https://jsfiddle.net/n1td79jm/3/ its working here.